# How to set icon right side and bottom of TextInputEditText in android

Tags: java, android, xml, image, icons

How to set icon right side and bottom of TextInputEditText in android
[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBE35.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please post some code that you have tried, so people can offer you some solution. Do not expect to get full code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this trick

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/label"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_microphone"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```